# Is there a name for $\sum\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology

Is there a name for this function?
$$f(n,p)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\right\rfloor, \quad n,p\in \mathbb{N}$$
It's left unnamed [in the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A027868), [Wolfram Alpha doesn't recognise it](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+floor+n%2Fp%5Ei), but it's a common theme in some Project Euler problems and it seems important.

Comment: It's the $p$-adic valuation of $n!$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you very much for the quick response. If you post it as an answer, I'll be able to press "accept".

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: @Shaun cool! thanks, I didn't know

Comment: It is sometimes written $v_p(n!)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the $p$-adic valuation of $n!$, that is the largest number $m$
with $p^m\mid n!$.